# How to use Material's UI in React.js

Tags: reactjs, terminal

I tried using Material's UI in React, but it shows errors:

> ./src/Sidebar.js
> Module not found: Can't resolve '@material-ui/icons/Twittter' in
> 'C:\cleverprogrammer\twitter-clone\src'

How can it be solved and is there anything I need to do in my terminal?

Comment: Welcome. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and take the [tour]. You need to add more information to your post.

Answer (score 0):

From my expreince the only two steps you need to do is install material ui from npm

```
npm install @material-ui/core
```

Then add Roboto Font to your index html in `<head></head>`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed material ui icons?
Run

```
npm install @material-ui/icons
```